# Create new PayPal.Payments.DataObjects.TransactionResponse

Tags: c#, vb.net, paypal

Is it possible to create a new `PayPal.Payments.DataObjects.TransactionResponse`?

I'm currently working on upgrading (our old ERP system) to TLS 1.2, and I need to override a function that returns a `PayPal.Payments.DataObjects.TransactionResponse`, but `PayPal.Payments.Communication.PayflowNETAPI.SubmitTransaction` returns a string.  Trying to simply create a `new PayPal.Payments.DataObjects.TransactionResponse` hasn't worked - I'm told in the VB code that:

> 'PayPal.Payments.DataObjects.TransactionResponse.Private Sub New()' is not accessible in this context because it is 'private'.

Trying in the C# code yields a less descriptive error:

> 'TransactionResponse' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

(replacing the `0` with any number of arguments that you put in -- I tried up to 8 or 9)

I am open to solutions in either VisualBasic or C#.  Although the function in question is in VB, we opted to send our transactions to an internal processing server, which will return the string (written in C#), so I can do this from either side.

Basically, I just need to take the response (currently in string format), probably parse it (although a straight string conversion would be fine too), and put the info into a `PayPal.Payments.DataObjects.TransactionResponse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have source code [here](https://payflownetsdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#PFProSDK/src/PayPal/Payments/DataObjects/TransactionResponse.cs).

You can check which parameter send to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick read of the Paypal SDK code mentioned by Ygalbel, it looks like there is no new() function.  Rather, you would declare your var of type PayPal.Payments.DataObjects.TransactionResponse and then use the set and get accessors to set/get data in the class.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately there don't seem to be set accessors in the `TransactionResponse` type.

Comment: Sorry for my crude code, but you're saying that something like this does not work:

myObj PayPal.Payments.DataObjects.TransactionResponse

myHash Hashtable
myHash['PayflowConstants.PARAM_RESULT','val']

myObj.SetParams(myHash)

mymyResult mResult

myObj.get(mymResult)

Comment: SetParams seems to be the class 'put' equivalent and you have to give it all of the appropriate params via hashtable.  Ugly, but paypal didn't ask me.  :)